# Android: WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll() ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager

While the Android app is working normally on most devices, for some people this error occurs on Galaxy S4:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll(WindowManagerGlobal.java:325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3589)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: share your code to get help soon from SO...

Comment: This seems to be a general system error when the activity gets relaunched.